# simple retrieving image name from database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to retrieve an image that is stored in a database.. I am just trying to print the name of the image right now before I even try showing the image just so I can get better at this...

right now I have a table called categories with the fields categories_id, categories_image

This is my query in php:

```
<?php  
$category_image_raw = "select c.categories_image from categories c where c.categories_id in(41)"; 

echo $category_image_raw['categories_image']; ?>
```

the field category_id 41 has an image uploaded to it. this is not working. what am I missing?

Comment: is it the very first mysql query you are running from PHP?

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel basically yes.. Without editing one that was already made for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php  
$category_image_sql = "select c.categories_image from categories c where c.categories_id = 41;"; 
$category_image_query = mysql_query($category_image_sql);
$category_image_raw = mysql_fetch_array($category_image_query);
echo $category_image_raw['categories_image'];  
?>
```

Remember to login to mysql before.

Comment: Yes this works. So basically I was missing 2 things? making the actual query with mysql_query function and then retriving it into an array?